# If statement help Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
keyCounter = 0
key1Value = 0
key2Value = 0
key3Value = 0

print(key1Value)

key1Value = input("Press the first key.")
key2Value = input("Press the second key.")
key3Value = input("Press the third key.")
# password = 123

if key1Value == 1 and key2Value == 2 and key3Value == 3:
    print("Access Granted")
    print(key1Value)
    print(key2Value)
    print(key3Value)
elif   key1Value != 1 and \
       key2Value != 2 and \
       key3Value != 3:
       print("Access Denied")
       print(key1Value)
       print(key2Value)
       print(key3Value)
else:
    print("Vault error")
    print(key1Value)
    print(key2Value)
    print(key3Value)

input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Why does this always result in "Vault Error" ? I have looked around and I feel like my if conditions are wrong but I'm not sure.

Comment: Because `input` always returns a string. In other words you're trying to compare `1` to `'1'`. Use `int(input("Press the first key."))`.

Comment: If you enter in a code like `126` (were 2 of the values match, but one doesn't) you will get a "Vault Error" instead of "Access Denied".  You will only see "Access Denied" if *none* of the numbers match.  I'm not sure if that's the outcome you are looking for.  This may not be a problem here, but I just wanted to point out that the inverse of: `key1Value == 1 and key2Value == 2 and key3Value == 3` is actually `key1Value != 1 or key2Value != 2 or key3Value != 3` (This is due to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input method return the user input in a type of string, and you try to compare two different of types (int and str)

Change the comparisons to str, for example:

```
if key1Value == "1" and key2Value == "2" and key3Value == "3":
```

You can also cast the input into int:

```
key1Value = int(input("Press the first key."))
```

Notice that you will get an error when you won't insert an actual number.

**In conclusion**, I would do the following:

```
try:
    value=int(input("Press the first key."))
except ValueError:
    print("This is not a whole number.")
```

This way, you can check whether the user input is type of int, and if it's not an int type you can handle it in an appropriate way.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks!